# Learn Symfony2 or switch to Zend?

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, zend-framework2

My development team created a website with symfony 1.4, but the project turned out a nightmare : few knew how to code with symfony, we were too many working on the project, and we ended up with a mess hard to maintain.

Personally, I'm a symfony fan and can't wait the release of 2.0, but the team doesn't want to hear any of it, thinking Zend Framework will be better, since it is based on independent modules (but so is Symfony2, right ?)

In any case, I will insist devs have training on either sf2 or Zend before starting a new project.

Any thoughts ? Should I insist on using Symfony 2, or are they right in asking for ZF ?

Comment: This can't really be answered on SO, but let me just say if your dev's all favor and are comfortable with Zend, why force Symphony on them?

Comment: If the majority wants ZF, it would be better for the morale to use that. It is not worse for sure.

Comment: I feel they blame symfony for the project's failure

Comment: I agree that this question cannot really be answered based on facts, but I say a framework isn't going to stop a dev team from making a messy project that is hard to maintain. My suggestion is to have 2 developers work on a section and understand each other's work, that way if maintenance is required either of the two would be able to assist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Current Zend framework ( 1 ) is based for PHP > 5.2 .

Symfony2 on the other hand starts for PHP > 5.3 . In Symfony2 all are bundles.

If you are interested to play with the nice features of 5.3, you can ask them to switch to symfony2 . Also why don't you join the #irc or google groups and get help when you get stuck ?

Also its hard to convince someone who is against a framework. So better try to convince about PHP 5.3 and the improved features.

ZF2 is based on 5.3 but still in dev, and slowly coming the way.

Also its not a good way to blame a framework for your project fails :-)

If you are interested in PHP 5.3 frameworks I recommend

Symfony2 : http://symfony.com/ ( Components , a small framework Silex on top of Symfony2 components , Symfony2 full stack framework ) . Why I recommend Symfony2 is the components will be used by Drupal, PHPBB, PPI2 and many more. So you need to learn only one API :-).

Others

Flow3 : http://flow3.typo3.org/ version 1 . Localization and Translation not full to my knowledge. Uses Doctrine2 as ORM. From TYPO3 , not the greedy company :-) .

Lithium : http://li3.me/ ( Development )

ZF2 : http://framework.zend.com ( Development Beta-3 )

Interested in PHP 5.4 Framework / Components ?

Aura PHP ( Previously Solar PHP by Paul M Jones the father of Benchmarking frameworks ) : https://github.com/auraphp currently Beta2 as of updating.

Know more from http://auraphp.github.com